# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}$ converges to a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}$$ converges pointwise to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$

Using the boundedness of $\sin(n^2 x)$ and the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$, it was easy to show pointwise convergence.  Showing that the function is continuous is giving me a lot of trouble, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first, note that you can write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}.
$$
So, it is sufficient to show that the series on the RHS (without the $x$) converges to a continuous function.

Now, the functions $f_n(x):=\frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$; so, to show that the series is continuous, it is sufficient to show that convergence of the series is uniform on $\mathbb{R}$.  Can you see how to do that?

Comment: For all $\epsilon > 0$, $\sum_{k=m}^{n} |\frac{\sin (k^2 x)}{k^2}| \leq \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} < \epsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n,m \geq N$ where $N$ is sufficiently large.  Is this correct?

Comment: @GillyB Bingo.  Nicely done.